# podman - fedora 39 - log driver gelf not available

Tags: podman, gelf

When i try to use gelf as log drver i get an error:

```
Error: running container create option: invalid log driver: invalid argument
```

```
podman run \
--rm \
--detach \
--publish 9080:80 \
--network pasta \
--name nginx1 \
--hostname nginx1 \
--log-driver=gelf \
--log-opt=gelf-address=udp://192.168.1.26:12201 \
--log-opt=tag=nginx docker.io/nginx
```

```
Error: running container create option: invalid log driver: invalid argument
```

when i check "podman info", i see gelf driver is not there:

```
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
```

Anyone knows how to get gelf driver available for podman on Fedora 39?

Comment: It's not one of the options. See [`podman run --log-driver`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#log-driver-driver)